# Center content and Overlay FIGURE-MAP-SVG

Tags: html, positioning

I can't manage to center map and figure and overlay the two layers. I'm a bit confused with position:relative and position:absolute.

```
 HTML
<div style="text-align:center">
<p>Hello World!</p>

<figure id="mapa">
<img src="mapa.png" width="500" height="500" usemap="#map"/>
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <line x1="10" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100" stroke="red"/>
    <line x1="60" y1="100" x2="200" y2="300" stroke="red"/>
<line x1="200" y1="300" x2="400" y2="400" stroke="red"/>
</svg>
</figure>
</div>

CSS
<style>
figure{
position:relative;
}
img{
position:absolute;
}
svg{
position:absolute;
}
</style>
```

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/z3qf8u2e/

Answer (score 0):

just use `margin : 0 auto` instead https://jsfiddle.net/1zhdrvje/